# sp_setapprole and creating users / logins

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have set up SQL Server and our Application in such a way that an SQL Server login has … well no permissions when accessing the database using any tool, except our application. This is needed because some people might fire up access (or SQL Server Management Studio) and would be able to manipulate the data in that way.

So we set up an Application Role and gave that Application Role the necessary permissions. Everything works nicely, users can't access our tables unless they use our Application.

Now comes the problem. In our application it should be possible to Create additional logins / users, or set some specific users as being Administrators (only admins can do user related stuff). I'm not 100% certain but in that case I think the user needs SecurityAdmin role. So we have some code in our application which looks like this :

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  name
                FROM    sys.server_principals
                WHERE   name = @LoginName )
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN [' + @LoginName + '] WITH PASSWORD = '''
            + @Password + ''', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[' + @DBNAME
            + '], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF';
        EXECUTE(@SQL);
    END

IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  name
                FROM    sys.database_principals
                WHERE   name = @LoginName )
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'CREATE USER [' + @LoginName + '] FOR LOGIN ['
            + @LoginName + ']';
        EXECUTE(@SQL);
    END

IF EXISTS ( SELECT  name
            FROM    sys.server_principals
            WHERE   name = @LoginName )
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @LoginName, 'securityadmin'
    END
```

The problem is of course that the server_principals is in the Master Database, and there is no way I can give my Application Role those permissions. Is there any way to work-around this problem or an easy way to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, when you activate an Application Role (AppRole) , its security context completely supplants the security context of the User.  Although this can be reverted in the session(connection), the two security contexts (AppRole and User) cannot both be active at the same time.

Therefore, the usual way to use these two together is exactly how you have done it so far(*): that is, use the User/Login *only* to enable the right to connect to the database initially, then switch to the AppRole, to gain access to the databases contents.

However, if you want to enable different levels of permissions/rights within the database, you cannot do it through the Users/Logins (not solely anyway).  There are several different ways to approach this, but the simplest way to accomplish what you want is probably to have different AppRoles for different classes of application users.  So you could have an `ApplUser` role for most users, and an `ApplAdmin` role for users who are administrators, etc.  You would then grant these additional AppRoles, enhanced permissions and access within the database, as needed.

(* And **big** kudos for that.  This is a *very* good security scheme for SQL Server, but few application developers go through the effort to implement it.)

Comment: Well … actually my problem is I will need a good example on how to set this up I guess. For now I think I can set everything up with an AppUser application role and give that role all insert / select / update / execute rights for an application.

But what permissions should I give to the AppAdmin then in order to allow it to Create LOGINs and USERs on the SQL Server and allow them to set others as Admins and change other users passwords. Any suggestions on that, since that involves some stuff in the Master database which is outside of the scope of my Application Role. Or am I missing something

Comment: With my current setup I'm getting :

Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot alter the login 'test.gebruiker', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: @Stefaan yes, the other "obvious" way is application-implemented security (as opposed to DB-implemented): give your AppRole all necessary/admin access, then have your application logic determine/filter who can do what in the database as well as in the application.

Comment: @Stefan that ("*what privs for AppAdmin to create LOGINs*") is a somewhat different question.  I can think of one solution, but I don't like it, so I'd suggest that you take just that question ("*How can I setup an Application Role to do these things:...*") and ask it over at http://dba.stackexchange.com where hopefully, someone will have a better answer.  Be sure to include what you've tried, the error and if possible, enough info to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the EXECUTE AS clause in SQL Server:

[EXECUTE AS Clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx)

You can then put the logic into a stored procedure in the database, set this to execute as a different user (or owner if the owner of the database has the permissions to perform the operation).  All you need to do then is give the Application Role the permissions to execute the procedure, nothing more and the code itself will be executed as the other user.

Comment: By itself, this does not explain how to meet the goals of the OP: how to give some application-users more rights in the database than others.